# How do I position my image on the right side of my flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

So this is my code for a responsive website that I am currently creating, it works fine in the mobile version but as you can see, inside the

> @media property

where I am trying to move my image to the right side of the image container ( the red border container) but I am not able to do it, can someone please help me or tell me where is it that I'm mistaking the code.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap");

body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 70px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
.image_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
}
.text-container {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}
h1,
article {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.insights {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}
article {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
}

.stats_container {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.num1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 35px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.stats_heading {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
  font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  .card {
    width: 1040px;
    height: 450px;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .image_container {
    border: 1px red solid;
    width: 1040px;
    height: 450px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-content: flex-end;
  }
  .image {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;

    mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
  }
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <link href="firstproject.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image_container">
                <img class="image" alt="main.jpg"  src="image-header-desktop.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="text-container">
                <h1>Get <span class="insights">insights</span> that help your buisness grow</h1>
                <article>Discover the benfits of data analyitcs and make better decision regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.</article>
            </div>
            <div class="stats_container">
                <section class="stats">
                <div class="companies"><span class="num1">10k+</span>
                <span class="stats_heading">companies</span></div>
                <div class="templates"><span class="num1">314</span>
                <span class="stats_heading">Templates</span></div>
                <div class="queries"><span class="num1">12M+</span>
                <span class="stats_heading">queries</span></div>   
            </section>
            </div>
           
        </div>
</div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: it seems .image-container isn't a flex container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code.

1. I have wrap texts inside text-wrapper div.
2. I applied `display:flex;` to .card.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap");

body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 70px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
.image_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
}
.text-container {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}
h1,
article {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.insights {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}
article {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
}

.stats_container {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.num1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 35px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.stats_heading {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
  font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  
  .card {
    display:flex;
    width: 1040px;
    height: 450px;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .image_container {
    order:2;
    border: 1px red solid;
    width: 1040px;
    height: 450px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-content: flex-end;
  }
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="image_container">
                <img class="image" alt="main.jpg"  src="https://images.indianexpress.com/2020/08/Fujifilm-FB.jpg">
            </div>
          <div class="text-wrapper">
            <div class="text-container">
                <h1>Get <span class="insights">insights</span> that help your buisness grow</h1>
                <article>Discover the benfits of data analyitcs and make better decision regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.</article>
            </div>
            <div class="stats_container">
                <section class="stats">
                <div class="companies"><span class="num1">10k+</span>
                <span class="stats_heading">companies</span></div>
                <div class="templates"><span class="num1">314</span>
                <span class="stats_heading">Templates</span></div>
                <div class="queries"><span class="num1">12M+</span>
                <span class="stats_heading">queries</span></div>   
            </section>
            </div>
  </div>
           
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am really sorry and i am really thankful that you took a look at my issue, actually i got confused in position sides, I actually want to position my image on the right side but am not able to do it.

Comment: @Alucard Is that ok now?

Comment: @Alucard Or some more changes you want to do.

Comment: yes, thanks this would do

Comment: Your welcome, approve my answer and change img link before use.@Alucard

Comment: btw if you don't mind me asking, what does wrapping the text inside a text-wrapping div. do, specifically in this code and also the order in the .image-container

Comment: So in last i used 'order:2' property inside ".image_container" to move image at right side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237562/discussion-between-alucard-and-mr-lazy).